# BaconJS observable zip, sample property map fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactive-programming, rxjs, bacon.js

I am trying to produce the [zip example](http://baconjs.github.io/api.html#observable-zip) from BaconJS. But it doesn't work.

```
var obs = Bacon.fromArray([{ x: 1, y: 2 },
                           { x: 3, y: 4 }]);

var x = obs.map('.x');
var y = obs.map('.y');

var result = x.zip(y, function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
});

// This doesn't work
// if `result` is replaced with `x` then it produces 1, 3 correctly
result.onValue(function(value) {
  $("#events").append($("<li>").text(value))
});
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kghmkbdb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `Bacon.fromArray`, which behaves differently (synchronously) than other streams. This is a typical problem that many people run into in example code. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/FAQ#why-isnt-my-subscriber-called).

One way to solve this is to add `.delay(0)` to your stream, another is to use `Bacon.sequentially`.

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odaop1cs/) so it works.